# How to find out the ip address of bridge network in VirtualBox in headless mode?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have started virtualmachine using virtualbox in a remote machine (Cent OS) in headless mode with bridgenetwork settings. I have attached a hard disk which already has ubuntu 11.10 installed on it ?

Is there any way i can find out which ip address was allocated to the VirtualBox when it has started ?

I tried going through logs but i am not able to find anything ? I cannot do a remote desktop in to the machine, so i am wondering if i can somehow find out the ip address allocated  and then ssh in to the machine directly.

I am not sure how possible is this but i just wanted to ask if any one has encountered this kind of situation.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The guest IP address is chosen by the DHCP server in the network your host system is attached to. As bridged network traffic is directly transfered into the hosts network adapter you will not find anything in the logs on the host system.

Therefore there are two possibilities:

1. Use the MAC address of the guest system and try to compare it with the data from the DHCP server
2. If the guest is in the same subnet as the host perform a full nmap subnet scan with running guest and afterwards with paused/shutdown guest. One of the missing hosts for the second scan should be the virtual machine.
3. Check the `vbox` file that belongs to the virtual machine. Usually the generate MAC address for each network adapter can be found in it. Filter for `MACAddress=` - as XPath:
   `VirtualBox/Machine/Hardware/Network/Adapter[@MACAddress]`

Comment: Thank you. I have overcome the problem when the system administrator allowed me to do X forwarding.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's on the same subnet as your host machine, you could run an IP scanner and just look for IP addresses that are in use.  If your host is Windows, then Angry IP Scanner is a good choice (there are other choices too).  If your host is Linux, and install and use arp-scan.  The command

> arp-scan -l

will scan the subnet that you are currently on, and show IP addresses matched with MAC addresses.  The Virtualbox network settings should tell you what your guest's MAC address is.